# Display profile picture of some facebook friends (with the id) in a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview

I work on facebook graph api. And I've allready get the id of users which have using my app. I can  display the id of users and what I want to do , It's display in each cell of my tableview a FBProfilePictureView for the good user.

```
  [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {}

     NSString* fql =
     @"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=true AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

     [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                  parameters:@{ @"q" : fql}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                               FBRequest *fql = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"fql"];
                               [fql.parameters setObject:@"SELECT uid,name,is_app_user FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())" forKey:@"q"];

                               [fql startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                 id result,
                                                                 NSError *error) {
                                   if (result) {


                                       NSArray *arrayRsult = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

                                       NSMutableArray *ids = (NSMutableArray *) [arrayRsult valueForKey:@"uid"];
                                       NSMutableArray *names = (NSMutableArray *) [arrayRsult valueForKey:@"name"];

                                       recentFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                       idFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];










                                       for (NSDictionary *c  in ids)
                                       {
                                           [idFriends addObject:c];



                                       }


                                        arrayLength = [recentFriends count];




                                       NSLog(@"ids are : %@ ",idFriends);

                                       NSLog(@"there are %i", arrayLength);
```

I 've allready done , to begin , display my facebook profile picture in each cell with this code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
FBProfilePictureView *prof = [[FBProfilePictureView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30)];

[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         prof.profileID = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
     }
 }];

            [cell addSubview:prof];
```

}

I don't use custom cell and nib for custom cells. 
I don't know how to create an array for this table. 
I've tried this code  `cell.imageView.image = [idFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
  (idFriends is declared in the .h file as  __block NSMutableArray )
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can display profile picture of user in `UITableViewCell`, you can use default ImageView of Cell. You can get profile picture of user with its `Facebook ID` as following..

To get Small/Thumb Image of Profile use

`http://graph.facebook.com/<Friends Facebook ID>/picture?type=small`

You can also try following parameters in `type`, normal, large, square

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/517267866/picture?type=small"]];
UIImage *profilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Given code will grab the image from URL and assign that `UIImage` to your `UIImageView`

if you want more detail about it please just [Read Documentation here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

```
cell.imageView.image = profilePic;
```

Comment: Ok thanks! and is there a way to display some friends profile picture in differents cells using FBProfilePictureView instead of cell.image.image ?

Comment: just pass that friends facebook id in that url and get its image for particular cell in tableview

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/147083812025874/picture?type=medium          i cant so the image and any thing . i am new in ios. so plz help me

Comment: @AppleMap there are only 3 supported types `thumbnail, normal, & album`. so if you pass `medium` it will not return image. try any of the 3 and enjoy. even the error itself is explaining you, if you look it carefully :)

Comment: Thank x Dipen... Plz Give me any Good and proper Demo link ?

Comment: documentation link is there in my post, you can find any of the url there.

Comment: i am using the same way, but it is so slow to get pics. I mean, i have an dummy image on my image view and after i got the pic from FB the imageview is setted by profile pic. but everytime i see first this dummy image and after 1 sec comes the profile pic from FB. is there any way, first the imageview has profile pic then cell loads?

Answer (score 0):

Actually using "http://graph.facebook.com//picture?type=small" to fetch the profile image of the user or even their friends is slow.

A better and faster way of doing it to add a FBProfilePictureView object to your view and in it's profileID property, assign the user's Facebook id.

For example:
 FBProfilePictureView *friendsPic;

friendsPic.profileID = @"1379925668972042";